# Filter rows in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have one data source (Cloud SQL), and a page where I list the data. I want to create another page where I should only see the data that meets a condition.

I have tried to create a query, but it doesn't works...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is due to the fact that you have a function but you are not invoking it. Get rid of the function and just leave the following line of codes:

```
query.filters.approver._contains = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
return query.run();
```

I believe this should make it work. Take a look at the example provided in the **[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script)**. Hope it helps!